# How is multiparty computation (MPC) possible using Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum, corda, azure-blockchain-service

MPC involves running calculations on numbers, perhaps from different parties, and sharing the result without anyone seeing the underlying data. Even the person operating the computer cannot access the information

How is this possible on blockchains like ethereum/corda/hyperledger etc?

Comment: Have you looked into [Homomorphic Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption)? You could possible use this in conjunction with the blockchain.

Comment: How to use that on ethereum  or hyperledger ?

Answer (score 0):

Corda is a permissioned blockchain platform, which focuses on Peer to Peer communication. It is direct, private, and secured.

If there is any multiparty computation happening with in a Corda network, it will be happened only among participating parties.

1. It will happen strictly according to the Corda contract code, which
   is developed by the pre-agreed business rules.
2. Every transaction will collect digital signatures from the participating parties, and distributed the transaction to these participating parties when the transaction is done.

Please see more information at: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/key-concepts-ecosystem.html